# How to insert object with abstract parent in Core Data iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, orm

I create two entity in core data. First is Car(Abstract) with some attributes and second is SportCar(parent entity is Car) .

I generate swift classes from model in Xcode. Now I want to insert object of SportCar into database in code.

I don't know how do this correct way. Can anybody help me?

```
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    if let sportsCar = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SportsCar", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? SportsCar {

        sportsCar.maxSpeed = 20

    }
```

I guess that I have to add some code to sportCar class that enable me to get car attributes. Can anybody write my how to do it in convenient way?

Comment: What is your issue then? And why do you have a different entity for a sports car, what different attributes does it have?

Comment: I have different entity because I need to learn how to use abstract entity in Core Data and it is an example. I need to find a way how to insert object that is a sportsCar and contain attributes from parent class car(abstract).

Comment: Did you generate classes? You just set the properties. Note also that it's pretty rare to use abstract entities / parent entities in the real world.

Comment: Yes I generate classes but I don't know how can I put attributes from parent abstract class into child class. I try with add a method to child class but it's propably wrong way and generate error: [link](http://pastebin.com/0ui8czZe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the properties directly, either from the subclass:

```
self.carName = "Betty"
```

Or from outside:

```
sportsCar.carName = "Betty"
```

Comment: It works, I can't find it myself because Xcode syntax completion shows me only sportsCar attributes. But after your post I write `sportsCar.carName = "Betty"`and it's build successful. I will rely less on syntax completion in the future. Thank you very much Wain :)

Comment: I'd use mogenerator to create the classes, I like it more and completion works better too